# Can commands be written to support multi-line arguments, i.e. with new lines in them, as heredocs?

Tags: scala, sbt

## Overview

How might one write a sbt command that supports arguments with newlines in them as [heredocs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)?

I'd like to have an sbt command where the user can paste a multi-line block of text that is then processed/converted into something else. Experiments so far seem to indicate that sbt attempts to parse the command immediately after a newline is encountered.

## Usage Example

*Note: this is just a use case to explain the desired SBT functionality. I am **not** looking for other mechanisms to process `pom.xml` files in SBT; rather, how one implements a custom command that has multi-line arguments.*

Suppose I'd like the ability for the user to paste a fragment of XML code from a Maven POM file into the SBT REPL and have it convert all the dependencies into SBT syntax. Here's an implementation that works if the XML code is all on a single line:

```
// NB: Requires SBT >= 0.13.5
package pomhelpers

import sbt._
import Keys._
import sbt.complete.Parser
import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers._
/** 
 * Plugin to install an SBT command to assist in converting Maven dependency syntax
 * to SBT DSL.
 */
object ExtractMvnDependencies extends AutoPlugin {
    override def trigger = allRequirements
    override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(commands ++= Seq(pomLibs2Sbt))

    val Pom2SbtCommand = "pom2sbt"
    val Pom2SbtHelp = "<pom-xml-fragment>"

    // **How should this be constructed to handle mult-line inputs?**
    val MultiLineCommandInputParser: Parser[String] =  
        OptSpace ~> (StringBasic | StringVerbatim)

    lazy val pomLibs2Sbt = Command(
        Pom2SbtCommand, 
        Help((Pom2SbtCommand, Pom2SbtHelp)))(_ => MultiLineCommandInputParser) { (state , xmlFrag) =>

        val sbtdeps = pomXml2SbtDsl(xmlFrag)
        println(sbtdeps.mkString("\n"))
        state
    }


    /** Convert POM string to SBT form. */
    private def pomXml2SbtDsl(xmlFrag: String): Seq[String] = {
        import scala.xml._
        val deps = XML.loadString(xmlFrag) \\ "dependency"
        deps map ((dependency) => {
            val coords = Seq("groupId", "artifactId", "version", "scope")
            val coordParts = coords.map(coord => (dependency \ coord).text.trim).filter(_.nonEmpty)
            coordParts.mkString("\"", "\" % \"", "\"")
        })
    }
}
```

With this plugin installed, one can run the following in the SBT REPL:

```
pom2sbt "<dependency><groupId>org.foo</groupId><artifactId>megalib</artifactId><version>1.1.1</version></dependency>"
```

or

```
pom2sbt """<dependency><groupId>org.foo</groupId><artifactId>megalib</artifactId><version>1.1.1</version></dependency>"""
```

and get:

```
"org.foo" % "megalib" % "1.1.1"
```

Which is the correct output, but reformatting the input string to fit on one line defeats most of the utility benefit.

The desired capability is to (in this case, and in the general multi-line command argument case) type `pom2sbt """`, paste the whole multi-line text block, end with `"""`, and have SBT delay parsing of the whole command until the closing heredoc delimiter, like this:

```
pom2sbt """<dependency>
<groupId>org.foo</groupId>
<artifactId>megalib</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>"""
```

However, even when using the `StringVerbatim` parser as in the example code, SBT gives you a parse error after the first newline:

```
> pom2sbt """<dependency>
[error] Expected '"""'
[error] pom2sbt """<dependency>
[error]                        ^
>     <groupId>org.foo</groupId>
[error] Expected symbol
[error] < usage:
[error] 
[error] 
[error] More command help available using 'help <command>' for:
[error]   <
...
```

Comment: Could you demo how a user would be supposed to execute such a command in sbt shell or command line? Or do you want a input task perhaps?

Comment: Just updated question with working code to clarify use case. Not sure if an `InputTask` is what I want or not… Perhaps an answer clarifying when one would use an `InputTask` over a `Command` when implementing this sort of thing would indeed be what I need to know.

Comment: It's clearer now. Thanks! Would https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pom-reader help in any way or is your sole requirement to fully convert pom deps to sbt format of ModuleID with `%`s?

Comment: BTW, why do you want to have multiline pasting feature rather than reading the file it was copied from?

Comment: The "pom transformation use case" is just an example to explain what I want (from some internal code that uses `fileParser` to instead). I'm really am looking to determine if there's a way to go into a "heredoc" or "paste" mode with custom sbt commands, regardless of the use case.

Comment: I *suspect* the issue here is when the command line (jline) passes the  command line values to sbt. On Unixes you need to escape the new line to avoid the shell to execute a command and I *think* the same happens here. I don't know if there's a way to avoid the execution mode and enter multiline one.

Comment: Yes, that was my suspicion as well, but I was hoping for a definitive answer from the SBT developers/maintainers to help determine if it was worth chasing the idea further (hence the bounty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue here is with the command line handler (using jline) passing command line values to sbt too prematurely. On Unixes you need to escape the new line to avoid the shell to execute a command and I think the same happens here.

I don't know if there's a way to avoid the execution mode and enter multiline one, though. I also don't think that sbt offers the feature.

Upon closer investigation, [LineReader](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/util/complete/src/main/scala/sbt/LineReader.scala) reveals all the line handling. My understanding of how it's used in sbt tells me that there's no way to instruct sbt to keep reading lines until a keystroke or a special value gets entered.

The [shell](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/command/src/main/scala/sbt/BasicCommands.scala#L160) internal command does the job of instantiating FullReader and then reading lines so to see it in the code that's where the machinery gets instantiated.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks so much for the help. @JoshSuereth also offered some comments on [sbt-dev](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sbt-dev/CBTaq1N0z7w/discussion).