# Multiline command in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

Is it possible to write a command inside sbt's shell using multiple lines?

For example, suppose I'm inside the sbt project for `scalac` itself:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:scala/scala.git
$ cd scala
$ sbt
> run file1.scala file2.scala file3.scala
```

Can I pass arguments to the `run` command on multiple lines? In bash, opening a single `'` or a double quote `"`, or writing a `\` at the end of a line allows command to spawn across multiple lines, is there an equivalent feature in `sbt`?

Comment: Did you try yourself? Give me a example of your input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can commands be written to support multi-line arguments, i.e. with new lines in them, as heredocs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855996/can-commands-be-written-to-support-multi-line-arguments-i-e-with-new-lines-in)